# How can I use MySQL with Python 3.3 and Django 1.5?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django needs MySQL-python package to manipulate MySQL, but MySQL-python doesn't support Python 3.3. I have tried MySQL-for-Python-3, but it doesn't work.
Please help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't. Use postgres.

Comment: 1. Don't use MySQL. 2. Python3 support in Django 1.5 is experimental anyway. Use Python 2.7.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This question is more applicable now, as Django recommends using Python 3.x if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.5 works under Python 2.7, so you need the MySQL-python package for that distribution of Python; just do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle now has a MySQL connector for Python 3.3 that works with Django.  See [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).

After you install, use `mysql.connector.django` for your `ENGINE` value under `DATABASES` in your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, Python 3 support in Django 1.5 is "experimental" and, as such, not everything should be expected to work.

That being said, if you absolutely need to get this working, you may be able to run the `2to3` tool on a source version of MySQL-python to translate it to Python 3 (and build against Python 3 headers if required).

Comment: Personally I would not recommend this at all.

Comment: Notice the "if you absolutely need to get this working" line. I wouldn't recommend it either, but "don't do that, regardless of why you need to" isn't a helpful answer.