# Error doing Django manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

Sorry for this type of silly question. I am a noob into Django. I was following Django Official tutorial and At the stage of **python3 manage.py syncdb** i got this huge error

```
    Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 39, in get_for_model
    ct = self._get_from_cache(opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 29, in _get_from_cache
    return self.__class__._cache[self.db][key]
KeyError: 'default'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 46, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 171, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 294, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s  AND `django_content_type`.`app_label` = %s )' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 397, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 390, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 240, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 182, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 82, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(db).get_for_model(klass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 47, in get_for_model
    defaults = {'name': smart_text(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 373, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 856, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 711, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 777, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 46, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 328, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 46, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 171, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 294, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s  AND `django_content_type`.`app_label` = %s )' at line 1")
```

I have successfully installed python3 , mysql driver. Using ubuntu.
Here is my setings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'blog',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'hellyeah',
        'HOST' : '',
        'PORT' : ''
    }
}
```

It would be awesome if somebody teach me whats wrong..

Comment: MySQL-python doesn't support Python 3.3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202503/how-can-i-use-mysql-with-python-3-3-and-django-1-5. The official page says support is on the way http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Comment: Owh, Thanks.. Now it seems i tried to learn python for nothing... 
Better i go back to php

Comment: @user2665252 er, what? All he said was that that library isn't compatible with python 3. Use Python 2.7 instead, or find a MySQL library that is compatible with version 3.3.

Comment: Or try some other database engine. PostgreSQL for example. But really, if the only productive thing I did today was converting someone from Python back to PHP, I'll go kill myself...

Comment: Don't worry, Trying with python 2.7

Comment: sqlite3 is really easy to use, try that to start. The ORM makes it easy to move to postgres later if you want.

Comment: There is no reason to use Django with Python3, due to it is experimental and just a start and not for production. In addition it's command line does not give exact error when used with python3.

Comment: You are right. That time i didn't knew much about django. And my class was teaching python 3.3 so thought 3.3 will be better in everyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Python 3 with django. There is no driver currently available for it. Since you're starting with django and Python, why not use Sqlite, it has a good Python3 driver, and will suffice for your learning experience.

You may also try using Postgres, but that has a lot more setting up to do than Sqlite.

Comment: As an update to this you can use mysqlclient as the connector and it should work:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient